# why is there a Wordcloud error in Python?

Tags: python, word-cloud

I keep getting error which is wordcloud is not defined.
I am not sure where is my mistake on the script.

```
# Display your wordcloud image
wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=40, relative_scaling=.5).generate(text)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()

#Error: name 'WordCloud' is not defined
```

Comment: This is the top part of the script. /                 
    # LEARNER CODE START HERE
                                                                                                                                           
    freq = dict ()
    for words in text_tokens:
        if words in stopwords:
            continue
        if words in freq:
            freq[word] += 1
        else:
            freq[word] = 0
    return freq

    #wordcloud
    cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
    cloud.generate_from_frequencies()
    return cloud.to_array()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). On Stack Overflow it's best to ask a specific question after having done "enough" research on your own trying to find an answer yourself (see also [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5698098); and the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/5698098)).

Answer (score 1):

`WordCloud` is not a default class in Python. Assuming you have already installed the Python package, you are going to have to import it.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud #This line here

wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=40, relative_scaling=.5).generate(text)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```